# laravel live-wire comment system N+1 problem Occur

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I create the comment section and everything work fine but I have an n+1 problem and I quit don't know how to solve it I have Debug  the application to check where the problem here What Happen

I am Creating an App like Instagram

First I load the post of the user and The one he follows In for each loop Here is the Query

```php
$ids =  Auth::user()->followings->pluck('id');
$ids->push( Auth::user()->id);
$posts= Post::with('user', 'comments', 'likers')->whereIn('user_id', $ids)->latest()->get();
return view('dashboard', [
    'posts' =>$posts
    'user' => Auth::user()
]);
```

For Each loop
I have Strip the Unnesserry Code

```php
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <livewire:comments :post="$post" />
@endforeach
```

So for Everything Work, Fine Here Occurs The Problem

Livewire Comment Component

```php
public function mount($post)
{
    $this->post = $post;
}

// This is the Method The Work Fine But I Want Pagination

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.comments', ['comments' => $this->post->comments]);
}

// and If I use The pagination I Ran Into n+1 Problem 

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.comments', ['comments' => $this->post->comments()->paginate(5)]);
}
```

if You have Any Question I if you need I extra Information Just Tell Me ok

best Regards